# BankID and CURL ERROR 77 or CURL ERROR 60

Tags: php, ssl, curl, bankid

I've spent a few hours trying to get cURL (in PHP) to work with the Swedish [BankID service](https://www.bankid.com/utvecklare), and running into the following two certificate errors:

```
CURL ERROR 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

CURL ERROR 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:\test\bankid\bankid_test_server.pem
  CApath: C:\test\bankid\bankid_test_server.pem
```

The code I'm using to initialize cURL is the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$bankidServerCertFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$bankidServerCertFile);
        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $clientCertFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $clientCertPass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $clientCertKeyFile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $clientCertKeyPass);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
```

I've tried various variations of the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` and `CURLOPT_CAPATH` options, but I still get either of the two errors (when I try some variations of the options I get one, when I try some other variations I get the other error).

I got the server certificate by following the advice to export it using Firefox, as described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130271/php-curl-and-ssl-certificate-or-cert-chain). The certificate file is in the correct location and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the content of the certificate file itself.

First, exporting it using Firefox doesn't give you the correct certificate. It should be downloaded from [the BankID integrations guide](https://www.bankid.com/en/utvecklare/guider/teknisk-integrationsguide/miljoer). Look under the expanding header `Issuer of server certificate` in either the `Production environment` or `Test environment` sections, and copy the actual certificate string starting with

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

and ending with

`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

(including the starting- and ending lines).

Second, that still won't work with cURL if you just paste it in a text file as it is. It seems that it needs to be formatted in a certain way, more precisely broken down into 64 character long lines.

You can use an online tool, such as [samltool.com - Format a X.509 certificate](https://www.samltool.com/format_x509cert.php) to do this. Paste the text you copied into the field `X.509 cert`, press `Format X.509 certificate`, then copy the text from the field `X.509 cert with header`. Paste this into the certificate file on your server (in my case `C:\test\bankid\bankid_test_server.pem`). The file should now start with

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`

followed by a bunch of 64 character long lines, and ending with

`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

If it still doesn't work, make sure that the path to the certificate file is correct, that it is readable by PHP and that you copied the correct (production/test) certificate depending on if you're calling the test- or production URL's.